# Vue.js - Reverse back after npm run build

Tags: vuejs2, restore, npm-run

I have made a website with Vue.js and i have `npm run build` it. After that it will create a dist folder that contain your CSS, image, JavaScript, index.html and so on. But now i have lost my project folder and have only the dist folder.

How can i convert it back to before i have use `npm run build` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's like trying to split a cake back to ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you *can* if you have connected it to git and just undo changes from source control

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).